# How to increment a for loop with a decimal value in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, increment

I have this code

```
for (k=0; k<BUFFER_LEN; k++){                

           buffer[k] = sin(2*pi*f/fs*k);          //sine generation
```

my loop increments by 1 each time - so k will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... etc for each calculation

I would like the loop to increment by 0.1 each time for example, so my sine calculation is more accurate?
What would be the simplest way to achieve this? I tried incrementing by 0.1 in that for loop but  dont think this is allowed as the program times out

edit: here is a solution

```
int i, k;
float z=0.1;

for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; i++){                         // fill the buffer
       buffer[k] = sin(2*pi*f/fs*z);                     // sine wave value generation
       z = z + 0.1;
       }
```

Comment: Are you incrementing an `int` by `.1` adding `.1` will just get you back the same number due to truncation? It would be more helpful if you provided a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: this question needs a bit more information about what you'd like to have in `buffer` at then end of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Solution:  **Multiple by your desired gain**

```
double gain = 0.1;
for (k=0; k<BUFFER_LEN; k++) {                
  buffer[k] = sin(gain * 2*pi*(f/fs)*k);          //sine generation
}
```

*No* need to change your k loop, BUFFER_LEN & no floating point issues.  1/Gain does not need to be an integer.

---

Your original problem was likely due to:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k<BUFFER_LEN; k += 0.1) {                
  buffer[k] = sin(2*pi*f/fs*k);          //sine generation
}
```

In this case, the `k += 0.1` did `k = (int) (k + 0.1)`  which truncates the sum back to the original k.  Thus your loop runs forever.

Comment: Yep! so simple i should have thought of that myself - yes your right, if i tried to increment with a non-integer the loop just ran forever - many thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is increment by .1, your `k` value needs to be a float. After that, it's as simple as this:

```
for(double k = 0; k < limit; k += 0.1)
```

But the over usage of decimal values could cause rounding errors, and your code needs k to be a whole number. Here is perhaps a better solution:

```
for(int k = 0; k < limit * 10; k++){
    //Now, in your equation, use k/10.0
    buffer[k] = sin(2 * pi * f / fs * (k / 10.0));
}
```

Make sure the size of `buffer` is ten times what it would need to be!

Comment: you should probably remove the `double` option, as the buffer array cannot be indexed by it

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be:

```
for (double k=0; k<BUFFER_LEN/10; k+=0.1){                

           buffer[10*k] = sin(2*pi*f/fs*k);
```

But rounding errors could lead to a wrong result. That's why you should use integer arithmetic in the loop and multiply in the loop by 0.1.

I'll leave this as a reminder what not to do.

Comment: If `k` equals e.g. 1.1, what does `buffer[1.1]` mean?

Comment: @Qiu: true, corrected.

Comment: Should `BUFFER_LEN` be an integer (a likely occurrence), `BUFFER_LEN/10` will perform integer division.  Example `for (float k=0; k<4/10; k+=0.1)`  will iterate 0 times rather than expected 4.

Comment: Due to rounding errors, using floating point in a loop iteration, as this code does, may overrun the desired endpoint and will have increasing rounding errors during the loop. Iteration counting should be done with integer arithmetic.